# How to get the matrix of samples having distance greater than 0.5

Tags: r

I know it is very basic thing, I searched a lot, but I did not find any solution.
 I have a binary matrix of genes(row) and samples(col), I wanted to calculate distance/similarity between samples based on the presence=1/absence=0 of gene in samples.
 I created a distance matrix using dist function,but I could not find the way to extract a sample-pairs matrix having distance greater than 0.5.
        I have file "data.txt" which contains binary data genes (row) and samples(col),
Reading binary file

```
table<-read.table("data.txt",header=TRUE,row.names=1,sep="\t")
```

calculating distance matrix

```
distance<-dist(table[1:15,1:15],method="binary", upper=TRUE,diag=TRUE)
```

> distance
>             x200032   **x200299**   x200203   x200078   x200108   x200024   **x200014**   x200239
>   x200032 0.0000000 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.1500000 
>   x200299 0.1000000 0.0000000 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.1500000 
>   **x200203** 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.0000000 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.1000000 **0.6000000** 0.1500000 
>   **x200078** 0.1000000 **0.5000000** 0.1000000 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.1000000 0.1000000 0.1500000 
>   x200108 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.0000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.1578947

I want to get the sample-pair which have distance greater than 0.5 (image attached rounded in red rectangle) as matrix or data frame object with sample names not the index

> distance
>          **x200299**   **x200014**
>   **x200203** 0.1000000 **0.6000000** 
>   **x200078** **0.5000000** 0.1000000

Thanks in advance for your kind answers.

Comment: Please consider to use `dput` to show the dataset ie. `dput(head(yourdata))`

Comment: You shouldn't call your data.frame "table" as it is a function's name in R. Also, if your samples are in columns, your distance matrix contains distances between genes, not samples... Could you tell exactly what you're expecting as output ? Do you want to remove rows/columns for which all distances are <= 0.5 ?

Comment: Thanks akrun for you response, you are right that it will calculate the distance between genes, I forget to mention one step,I transposed data, so finally I have sample in row and genes in col, here is the binary input file 
> `dput(head(table[1:15,1:15]))`
structure(list(WBGene00000001 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L),.....  WBGene00000003 =c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), .Names = c("WBGene00000001",........"WBGene00000017"
), row.names = c("x200032", ... "x200024"), class = "data.frame")
Yes, in output, I want to remove rows/columns for which all distances are <= 0.5. sorry I have word limitation